# Android: Upload edited photo without storing in local storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am developing an Android application with a Firebase Backend. Users are allowed to edit and post pictures. Everytime a picture is edited and is to be uploaded, I have to store the edited picture in local storage of the phone and then upload it on Firebase.

Apps like Instagram have stories where pictures are edited and uploaded in their database, but are not stored in the local storage of the phone.

I want to achieve the same thing of uploading a picture in a database, without storing it in the user's phone (local storage).
Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You always can delete the picture once it uploaded to firebase storage

Comment: Yeah, that is something I thought of, though it didn't seem convincing that apps like Instagram would be adopting this method of saving->uploading->deleting

Answer (score 1):

you can save it in your app specific folder and after successful delete it without storing in gallery.